# How to migrate my Foreground service to ns CLI 6.0?

Tags: android, angular, typescript, nativescript

When i try migrate to nativescript 6.0 or above I have a problem with starting my foreground service. This code works fine with ns 5.1... but on 6.0 I have error like below: Didn't find class "com.tns.ForegroundService" on path: DexPathList

> **log:** 08-28 20:02:45.119 14983 14983 I JS      : start freground 08-28 20:02:45.150 14983 14983 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   --------- beginning of crash 08-28 20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-28 20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E
>   AndroidRuntime: Process: org.nativescript.TabNavigation, PID: 14983
>   08-28 20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service
>   com.tns.ForegroundService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't
>   find class "com.tns.ForegroundService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.nativescript.TabNavigation-d2wbgYdHKRNbKAzPZK6rVg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.nativescript.TabNavigation-d2wbgYdHKRNbKAzPZK6rVg==/lib/arm64,
>   /data/app/org.nativescript.TabNavigation-d2wbgYdHKRNbKAzPZK6rVg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /system/lib64]] 08-28 20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3721)
>   08-28 20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:235) 08-28
>   20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1784)
>   08-28 20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 08-28
>   20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 08-28 20:02:45.154 14983 14983
>   E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986) 08-28
>   20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 08-28 20:02:45.154
>   14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>   08-28 20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445) 08-28
>   20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.tns.ForegroundService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.nativescript.TabNavigation-d2wbgYdHKRNbKAzPZK6rVg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.nativescript.TabNavigation-d2wbgYdHKRNbKAzPZK6rVg==/lib/arm64,
>   /data/app/org.nativescript.TabNavigation-d2wbgYdHKRNbKAzPZK6rVg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /system/lib64]] 08-28 20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
>   08-28 20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379) 08-28
>   20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) 08-28
>   20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:103)
>   08-28 20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(CoreComponentFactory.java:68)
>   08-28 20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3716)
>   08-28 20:02:45.154 14983 14983 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 8 more
>   08-28 20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err: An uncaught Exception
>   occurred on "main" thread. 08-28 20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W
>   System.err: Unable to instantiate service com.tns.ForegroundService:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.tns.ForegroundService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.nativescript.TabNavigation-d2wbgYdHKRNbKAzPZK6rVg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.nativescript.TabNavigation-d2wbgYdHKRNbKAzPZK6rVg==/lib/arm64,
>   /data/app/org.nativescript.TabNavigation-d2wbgYdHKRNbKAzPZK6rVg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /system/lib64]] 08-28 20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err: 08-28
>   20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err: StackTrace: 08-28 20:02:45.159
>   14983 14983 W System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate service com.tns.ForegroundService:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.tns.ForegroundService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.nativescript.TabNavigation-d2wbgYdHKRNbKAzPZK6rVg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.nativescript.TabNavigation-d2wbgYdHKRNbKAzPZK6rVg==/lib/arm64,
>   /data/app/org.nativescript.TabNavigation-d2wbgYdHKRNbKAzPZK6rVg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /system/lib64]] 08-28 20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err:    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3721)
>   08-28 20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err:    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:235) 08-28
>   20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err:    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1784)
>   08-28 20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err:    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 08-28
>   20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err:    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 08-28 20:02:45.159 14983 14983
>   W System.err:    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986) 08-28
>   20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err:    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 08-28 20:02:45.159
>   14983 14983 W System.err:    at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>   08-28 20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err:    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445) 08-28
>   20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err: Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.tns.ForegroundService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file
>   "/data/app/org.nativescript.TabNavigation-d2wbgYdHKRNbKAzPZK6rVg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.nativescript.TabNavigation-d2wbgYdHKRNbKAzPZK6rVg==/lib/arm64,
>   /data/app/org.nativescript.TabNavigation-d2wbgYdHKRNbKAzPZK6rVg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /system/lib64]] 08-28 20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err:    at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
>   08-28 20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err:    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379) 08-28
>   20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err:    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) 08-28
>   20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err:    at
>   android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:103)
>   08-28 20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err:    at
>   androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(CoreComponentFactory.java:68)
>   08-28 20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err:    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3716)
>   08-28 20:02:45.159 14983 14983 W System.err:    ... 8 more 08-28
>   20:02:45.188 14983 14983 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 14983 SIG: 9

I tried delete hooks, platforms, node-modules and add it once again. Didn't help.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
enter code here
    <service android:name="com.tns.ForegroundService" android:exported="false" 

enter code here
```

foreground-facade.service.ts:

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as app from 'tns-core-modules/application';
//import ContextCompat = android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ForegroundFacadeService {
  startForeground() {
    if (!app.android || !app.android.context) {
      return;
    }
    const foregroundNotificationIntent = new android.content.Intent();
    foregroundNotificationIntent.setClassName(app.android.context, 'com.tns.ForegroundService');
    foregroundNotificationIntent.putExtra('title', 'Serwis pobierania danych z pompy jest w trakcie działania');
    console.log("start freground");
    app.android.context.startForegroundService(foregroundNotificationIntent);
    //app.android.context.startForegroundService(foregroundNotificationIntent);
  }

  stopForeground() {
    const foregroundNotificationIntent = new android.content.Intent();
    foregroundNotificationIntent.setClassName(app.android.context, 'com.tns.ForegroundService');
    console.log("stop freground");
    app.android.context.stopForegroundService(foregroundNotificationIntent);
  }
}
```

foregroundservice.ts:

```html
import * as Application from 'tns-core-modules/application';

@JavaProxy('com.tns.ForegroundService')
export class ForegroundService extends android.app.Service {
  public onCreate(): void {
    super.onCreate();
  }

  public onDestroy(): void {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.stopForeground(true);
  }

  public onBind(param0: android.content.Intent): android.os.IBinder {
    console.log(param0);
    return null;
  }

  public onStartCommand(
    intent: android.content.Intent,
    flags: number,
    startId: number
  ) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    this.startForeground(1, this.createNotification(intent));
    console.log("start foreground onstartCommad");

    return android.app.Service.START_STICKY;
  }

  private createNotification(
    intent: android.content.Intent
  ): android.app.Notification {
    this.disableDozeMode();
    this.createNotificationChannel();
    return this.getNotificationBuilder()
      .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_plus)
      .setContentTitle('MED-LINK')
      .setChannelId('TNS-ForegroundService-1')
      .build();
  }

  private disableDozeMode() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
      const intent = new android.content.Intent();
      const context = Application.android.context;
      const packageName = context.getPackageName();
      const pm = context.getSystemService(
        android.content.Context.POWER_SERVICE
      );

      intent.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

      if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
        intent.setAction(
          android.provider.Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS
        );
        console.log('udalo sie usunac optymaliazacje baterii');
        intent.setData(android.net.Uri.parse('package:' + packageName));
        context.startActivity(intent);
      }
      else {console.log('NIEEEE EEEEE    udalo sie usunac optymaliazacje baterii');
            intent.setAction(
            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS
        );}

      // this.wakeScreenByActivity();
    }
  }

  private getNotificationBuilder() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 24) {
      // Not Oreo, not creating notification channel as compatibility issues may exist
      console.log('udalo sie  pdalic nb');
      return new   androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    }
    console.log('udalo sie  pdalic nb2');
    return new   androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this, 'TNS-ForegroundService-1');
  }

  private createNotificationChannel() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 24) {
      // Not Oreo, not creating notification channel as compatibility issues may exist
      return;
    }
    //const importance =
      //android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
    const mChannel = new android.app.NotificationChannel(
      'TNS-ForegroundService-1',
      'TNS-ForegroundService-1',
      2
    );
    var nm = this.getSystemService(
      android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
    );
    nm.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
  }

  private getTitle(intent: android.content.Intent): string {
    const title = intent.getStringExtra('title');
    if (title) {
      return title;
    } else {
      return 'Running in background';
    }
  }

  public onStart(intent: android.content.Intent, startId: number) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
  }
}
```

On this config:

√ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
√ Component nativescript has 6.0.3 version and is up to date.
‼ Update available for component tns-core-modules. Your current version is 6.0.1 and the latest available version is 6.0.7.
‼ Update available for component tns-android. Your current version is 6.0.0 and the latest available version is 6.0.2.
‼ Update available for component tns-ios. Your current version is 6.0.1 and the latest available version is 6.0.2.
I have error: idn't find class "com.tns.ForegroundService" on path: DexPathList

but on this:
5.1 I don't have a error. 
Plese help me figure out How to migrate my service to newest ns

Answer (score 1):

NativeScript 6 uses Webpack only workflow, you will have to add the class path to `appComponents` array in your `webpack.config.js`.

```
// Add your custom Activities, Services and other Android app components here.
const appComponents = [
    "tns-core-modules/ui/frame",
    "tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity",
    resolve(__dirname, "path/to/foregroundservice")
];
```

Comment: OK I add appComponents like this: `const appComponents = [
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame",
        "tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity",
        resolve(__dirname, "../med-link-ui/src/app/shared/foregroundservice")
    ]; `   But now error ocurres when app try to deploy on phone, not like before when I click button.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct, did you try to log the array content and verified?

Answer (score 0):

Hi [adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11465958/adam-niedi)

Not sure if you ever got this right but I found I had to add the .ts to my path for it to work. But then got another error I am trying to fix now.

resolve(__dirname, "src/app/foreground.service.android.ts")

Hope this helps someone else who ends up here.